# How do I call _super() in new ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Here is my code. It was working fine in my old ember (ie:pre-0.4)

```
Ember.Router.reopen({
    startRouting: function() {
        this._super(); // This line shows some error
    },
    transitionTo: function(name, param) {}
});
```

Now I have upgraded to new ember(ie ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js). After that my jasmine shows some errors in my console. Can somebody please help with this? Here is my error console:

```
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:60  app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:22975
> doTransition app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:22830 
> app/common/route.js:24  app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:892 superWrapper
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:23085  app/common/route.js:52 
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:892 superWrapper
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:23116  app/common/route.js:39 
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:892 superWrapper
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:22460 
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:22486 eachHandler
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:22464 setupContexts
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:22363 collectObjects
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:22392 proceed
> app/libs/ember-v1.0.0-rc.1.js:22379 collectObject
```

Comment: Nothing has changed in the way _super is called. Please make a working fiddle that has the problem you described. I tried to recreate the error but everything is OK in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T4a6N/